# how to access mysql with Kamaillio

Tags: kamailio

I am trying to setup Kamailio with MySQL plugin. I setup the config as follows:

```
## your SIP domain
SIP_DOMAIN=example.org

DBENGINE=MYSQL

## database host
DBHOST=localhost

## database host
DBPORT=3306
```

When I run `kamdbctl create`, I get the following:

```
INFO: test server charset
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kamailio//kamctl/kamdbctl.mysql: line 117: [: =: unary operator expected
INFO: creating database kamailio ...
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ERROR: Creating database kamailio failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the password for mysql user 'root' was not introduced correctly or the user 'root' was not created in the mysql server with the full rights.